# Excel Compare Column

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel sheet which contains two columns with 600 borrowers. I want to compare two column and find out that which items are present in 1 column but not in the other column. For example in the sheet below I want to find all the names of the countries which are in column A but not in column B.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In C1: `=INDEX($A$1:$A$11, SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$11, $B$1:$B$6, 0)), (ROW($A$1:$A$11)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$11))+1), ""), ROW(1:1)))` (Thanks to [this page](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/01/13/what-values-are-missing-in-list-1-that-exists-i-list-2/))

Where `A1:A11` is your main list (no headers), and `B1:B6` is the "Column B".  Enter as an array, with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag down:

(You can wrap `IfError([above formula],"")` around it to clean it up when there aren't any matches.)

[image]

Comment: @Nomi - Can you expand on that? What happens when you use it? What error does it show, or what incorrect values does it return? It should work...?